# How to find limit of this fraction using L'Hopital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, fractions

I need to find the limit of these two fractions as $P$ goes to infinity.

$$v_0 = \frac{-\frac{\mu_k}{P} + \frac{\mu_k^2 c_k^2}{P^2} + s_A^2}{\sqrt{s_A^2 + \frac{\mu_k^2 c_k^2}{P^2}}}$$

$$v_1 = \frac{1-\frac{\mu_k}{P} + \frac{\mu_k^2 c_k^2}{P^2} + s_A^2}{\sqrt{s_A^2 + \frac{\mu_k^2 c_k^2}{P^2}}}$$

By plugging numbers in and graphing it seems that $v_1$ goes to infinity with $P$, but that $v_0$ converges to something finite.

I'd also appreciate it if someone could explain how l'Hopital's rule may or may not be useful in this problem.

Comment: Are other things like S,c are constant?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $\mu, c, s$ are constants, all small fractions go to $0$, which makes
$$
v_0 \to \frac{s_A^2}{\sqrt{s_A^2}} = |s_A|\\
v_1 \to \frac{1 - s_A^2}{\sqrt{s_A^2}}
$$

L'Hospital's rule is not useful here since both numerator and denominator are not of the form $0/0$ nor of the form $\pm \infty/\infty$.

Comment: Oh, duh! Thanks.